# How can I use STL sort in c++ to sort some values in the class?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have a class named Graph, in this class I have a member named V, it is a vector. I have a struct named Edge, and a list of Edges. like below:

```
struct Edge{
 int u;
 int v;
 Edge(int u,int v){
   this->u=u;
   this->v=v;
 }
};
struct Vertex{
 int d;
 int f;
 .
 .
 .
}

class Graph{
  vector < Vertex > V;
  .
  .
  .
  int edgeCmp(Edge* x,Edge* y){
    return ( V[x->v].d < V[y->v].d )?1:0;
  }
  void someFunction(){
   list<Edge> backEdges;
   backEdges.sort(&Graph::edgeCmp);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work!! may someone help me to do such a thing? I get this error:

Error   3   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility    346

It can't understand I'm calling the function which takes 2 arguments. I don't know why.

Comment: Next time, use the 101010 button to format code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a member function as the comparator. A member function needs the `this` pointer which cannot be passed from `sort`.

Instead, you have to create a function object to include the extra info, like:

```
class Graph{
  vector < Vertex > V;

  struct EdgeComparer {
     const vector<Vertex>& V;
     EdgeComparer(const vector<Vertex>& vertices) : V(vertices) {}
     bool operator() (const Edge& a, const Edge& b) const {
        return V[a.v].d < V[b.v].d;
     }
  };

  ...

  EdgeComparer ec (V);
  backEdges.sort(ec);
```

Note that, since you have a list of `Edge`, not `Edge*`, the input arguments of the comparator should *not* be `Edge*`. I have changed those to `const Edge&`.

Comment: thank you! it works. but may you explain it to me?I couldn't understand it well.

Comment: @Morteza: `.sort` can accept any object `f` that can be called like `f(a,b)`. Functions are an obvious type of them, but so are classes (structs) with overloaded `operator()`. The latter is called a function object. The advantage over normal functions is these can store an arbitrary state, like what is done here — the vertex vector `V` is included as an extra state of the function object, which is needed to compare the two Edge's.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (V[x->v].dv].d)?1:0;
```

This line has unbalanced brackets and is horrible to read (the former is a consequence of the latter I suspect). Without seeing your Vertex class it's hard to say what it is supposed to do - after fixing the brackets, maybe you should reformat for readability.

Comment: I added Vertex struct, but it is not the case. I get the error like this:
term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Comment: @Morte Try declaring `edgeCmp` as `static`. Also, you should change the return type to `bool` and drop the `?1:0` part.